# Reducing interline space in multiline descriptions in a table

Tags: tables

I need to

a) reduce the interline space in the descriptions that take multiple lines.

b) be able to control the width of columns so that the table looks better. For the current table I want a bit wider space between the columns.

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tabularx}  
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} 


\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h] %htbp
\caption{Nomenclature} 
\label{tab:des_vars}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l l Y@{}} 
\toprule
Notation & Supporting set & Description \\
\midrule
\hline
$y_{ijk}$ & $\{0, 1\}$ & 1 if there exists edge $(i, j)$\\
& & using the type $k$\\
\addlinespace
$a_{ij}$ & $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ & non-negative volume that\\
& & passes quickly through $(i, j)$  \\   
& & very very very very long description follows  \\ 
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you don't want the extra vertical space then you shouldn't add it manually with `\addlinespace`. But why do you use tabular new lines if you are using `tabularx`?

Comment: Thank you! I am not very proficient, just learning. Got it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to getting rid of most `\addlinespace` directives, you should also exploit the fact that your `Y` column type allows automatic line breaking within cells.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%%\usepackage{amsfonts} % 'amsfonts' is loaded automatically by 'amssymb'
\usepackage{amssymb}
%%\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500 % really?
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e} 
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X} 

%\usepackage{tikz} % not needed for this example
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\caption{Nomenclature} 
\label{tab:des_vars}

\smallskip
\footnotesize % <-- optional
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l l Y @{}} 
\toprule
Notation & Supporting set & Description \\
\midrule
$y_{ijk}$ & $\{0,1\}$ & $1$ if there exists edge $(i,j)$ using the type~$k$  \\
\addlinespace
$a_{ij}$ & $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ & Non-negative volume that passes quickly through $(i,j)$. \\
& & Very very very very long description follows.  \\   
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually the description "non-negative volume that passes quickly through $(i, j)$ " is referring to a_{ij}

Comment: @Vika - Thanks. So where does "very very very very long description follows" belong?

Comment: It belongs to a_{i,j}. I want a bit more space in between columns so that it looks better.

Comment: @Vika - I've updated my answer. Is this what you're looking for? If you want to increase the amount of whitespace between columns, you shoudl excecute (say) `\addtolength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}` or something similar. In the `elsarticle` document class, the default value of `\tabcolsep` is `6pt`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned @campa in his comment, you manually insert additional apace between rows. However, I would write your table on the following way:

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedRight}X}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht] %htbp
\caption{Nomenclature}
\label{tab:des_vars}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}l l R @{}}
    \toprule
Notation & Supporting set & Description \\
    \midrule
$y_{ijk}$ & $\{0, 1\}$ & 1 if there exists edge $(i, j)$ using the type $k$\\
    \addlinespace
$a_{ij}$ & $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ & non-negative volume that passes quickly through $(i, j)$  
                             very very very very long description follows\\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
now is considered edited question. BTW, `X` and from it derived column types break long lines automatically. This is shown in the second table row, so you not need to manually break long text between table rows ...

**Addendum:**
You may consider to use `tabularray` package for writing your table. Benefits: more flexible and shorter code;

```
\documentclass[preprint,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}
\interdisplaylinepenalty=2500
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}


\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]  
\caption{Nomenclature}
\label{tab:des_vars}
    \begin{tblr}{colsep=9pt,
                 colspec = {@{} Q[l, mode=math] 
                                Q[l, mode=math] X[l, cmd={\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}] @{}},
                 row{1}  = {mode=text},
                 row{2-Y}= {rowsep=5pt}
                 }
    \toprule
Notation & Supporting set & Description \\
    \midrule
y_{ijk} & \{0, 1\}  & 1 if there exists edge $(i, j)$ using the type $k$    \\
a_{ij}  & \mathbb{R}^{+} 
                    & non-negative volume that passes quickly through $(i, j)$  
                    very very very very long description follows    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I got the idea, but I want to use multiline descriptions potentially (see the updated question for more clarity)